# JS how to determine if key exists in JSON KVP structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, keyvaluepair

For JSON structured like so :

```
descriptors =   {"key1" :    { "propertyA": "propertyA-value1",
                               "propertyB": "propertyB-value1" },
                 "key2" :    { "propertyA": "propertyA-value2",
                               "propertyB": "propertyB-value2" }}
```

How to determine if a given key exists ?

```
# argKey is function arg supplied by caller
descriptor = descriptors[argKey]

if descriptor != undefined
  # do something with descriptor
```

Is that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not valid - you have `[ ]` brackets, which delimit an array, but you appear to be trying to put an object inside. You need this instead.

```js
descriptors =   {"key1" :    { "propertyA": "propertyA-value1",
                               "propertyB": "propertyB-value1" },
                 "key2" :    { "propertyA": "propertyA-value2",
                               "propertyB": "propertyB-value2" }};
```

That aside, to test for the presence of a property you can use the `in` operator.

```
'key1' in descriptors;
>> true
```

Since the test key is just a string, you can store it in a variable if it is not known ahead of time.

```js
var keyName = 'key1';
if (keyName in descriptors) {
    // do something
}
```

Per your question in the comments, to access the value of the property, you can say

```js
descriptors[keyName];

// More deeply nested example
var keyName = 'key1';
var propName = 'propertyA';
console.log(descriptors[keyName][propName]);
```

Comment: edited json to be valid ... but i need to lookup the object for a key unknown until runtime -- could be "key1" or "key2" or whatever the user specifies as an arg to the function

Comment: thanks but since my json structure is no longer an array but instead an object with properties how to extract object for a key unknown until runtime ?

Comment: ok so for json kvp structure the extraction syntax is similar to array element access

Comment: @BaltoStar Updated again with an example of that, but basically yes, same as arrays, but using strings instead of integers to fetch the value.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid JavaScript object. If you want to test the existence of a property on an object, use:

[Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score 0):

If the property exists and has value of `undefined` your solution won't work. Check it with `typeof` or `hasOwnProperty` instead:

```
var obj = {
    prop: undefined
};

console.log(obj.prop === undefined); // true
console.log(typeof obj.prop === undefined); // false
console.log(!obj.hasOwnProperty("prop")); // false
```